# Will ROLLBACK TRAN roll everything back?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Will `ROLLBACK TRAN` rollback everything in my SP? (including the call to another SP)

Example:

```
BEGIN TRAN

  INSERT INTO (table1)
  VALUES (1,'abc')

  EXEC InsertTable2

  INSERT INTO (table3)
  VALUES (1,'abc')

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: **Yes, of course!** A rollback will undo **everything** (**ALL DATA** manipulations) since the `BEGIN TRAN` - that's the **whole point** of a transaction....

Comment: @marc_s: Unless there is DDL inside the sproc - I'm not sure what the scope of ROLLBACK is when applied to various DDL commands.

Comment: @marc_s: at least commit doesn't commit everything in SQL Server. It merely decrements a "transaction counter". Only if that is zero, it's a "true" commit. Not sure if Rollback behaves the same. So if there is another `start transaction` inside the stored procedure the picture might be different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name IIRC, a ROLLBACK ignores nesting. If you encounter a rollback, it won't just roll back the innermost transaction, it will roll back all the way back to `trancount 0`

Comment: Also if the stored procedure starts a transaction but doesn't either commit or roll back, some developer's wrist needs to be struck with a ruler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from msdn

Rolls back an explicit or implicit transaction to the beginning of the transaction, or to a savepoint inside the transaction. You can use ROLLBACK TRANSACTION to erase all data modifications made from the start of the transaction or to a savepoint. It also frees resources held by the transaction.

so YES

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the definition of `InsertTable2` impossible to say for sure. Here's an example where it doesn't.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
Num int,
String char(3)
)
GO

CREATE PROC InsertTable2
AS
COMMIT;
BEGIN TRAN;

GO


BEGIN TRAN

  INSERT INTO table1
  VALUES (1,'abc')

  EXEC InsertTable2

  INSERT INTO table1
  VALUES (1,'abc')

ROLLBACK TRAN

GO

SELECT *
FROM table1

GO

DROP TABLE table1

DROP PROC InsertTable2
```

But assuming a sane definition the answer is "yes"

Comment: Nice and simple. I will name this example: `transaction injection`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will `ROLLBACK` everything in the `Store Procedure` that you have mentioned above.

More on [ROLLBACK TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms181299%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)